# Django ORM group by with IN

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Model:

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Post')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='User')
    rating = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Rating')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='add date', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'rating'
        ordering = ['-id']
```

Based on this model, need to make an analog of this query

Query:

```
select post_id, AVG(rating) from rating where post_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
group by post_id order by post_id
```

Tried to do so:

```
Rating.objects.values('post_id').filter(post_id__in=post_ids).annotate(avg_rating=Avg('rating'))
```

But in the end the query looks like this, and grouping on `id` field:

```
SELECT `rating`.`post_id`, AVG(`rating`.`rating`) AS `avg_rating` FROM `rating` WHERE `rating`.`post_id` IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) GROUP BY `rating`.`id` ORDER BY `rating`.`id` DESC
```

How to make grouping only `post_id` field?

Comment: or move this question to https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @U9-Forward, rewrites in english.

Comment: @ВладиславГусев Ok then

Comment: Override default ordering (`ordering = ['-id']`) with `...order_by('post_id', )`. Actually, I'd suggest to get rid of default ordering (defined in models' meta) totally.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, thank you, your solution helped me. Now I will know about ordering in the model.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, now answer my question, and i will mark your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override default ordering (`ordering = ['-id']`) with

```
...order_by('post_id', )
```